# Input 0 of layer "model_4" is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, mobilenet

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 244, 224, 3), found shape=(32, 224, 224, 3)

### Epoch 1/20

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history = ensemble_model.fit(X_train_scaled, Y_train, validation_split=0.2, epochs=20)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
13                 try:
14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
16                 except:
17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 244, 224, 3), found shape=(32, 224, 224, 3)
```